# How to find a basis for a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Considering the following matrix $A=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 3 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$, which has an eigenvalue of $\lambda=2$,  I need to find a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to the given eigenvalue.

So, basically I did $\ker(A-\lambda I)=0$, which resulted in $\ker(\left[ \begin{matrix} -1 & 1 & -1 \end{matrix} \right])$ after simplification.

That is equal to $-x_1+x_2-x_3=0$, but I'm stuck from there. How can I represent a basis for the matrix?

Comment: Which vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ fullfill $-x_1 + x_2-x_3=0$? Those are the eigenvectors for $\lambda=2$ (except $0$). You want to find a basis for them.

Comment: Your title is somewhat misleading.  You don't want a basis for a matrix (in the space of matrices), but you want a basis for one of the subspaces *associated* to a matrix (e.g., the column space, the row space, the kernel, or the kernel of the transpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $x_1=x_2-x_3$ and you can assign arbitrary values to $x_2$ and $x_3$, thus getting all solutions. In order to find two linearly independent solutions, choose first $x_2=1$ and $x_3=0$; then $x_2=0$ and $x_3$, getting the two vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
These are obviously linearly independent, by just looking at the second and third row.

Answer (score 1):

Since the solutions  are defined by the equation $\;x_3=x_2-x_1$, you have  an isomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbf R^2&\longrightarrow \ker(A-2I)\\
(x_1,x_2)&\longmapsto (x_1, x_2,x_2-x_1)
\end{align}
Remember an isomorphism maps a basis of the domain onto a basis of the image.